# gmail signin button white border when focused using tab

Tags: button, css

Could please show me code how to get this type of effect? I have gmail buttons code 
http://cssdeck.com/item/50/google-buttons, but this is not showing the effect I want. I checked google code. They are not using buttons instead of buttons they are using a `div` for better performance.

Thanks

Comment: You have the code here http://cssdeck.com/item/preview/50/google-buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. i Need to add below css code to get focus effect on buttons.

> .button:focus{
>       box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;
>   }